# Missing 802.1q module from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, kernel, tagging, vlan

I have just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I needed to add support for vlan tagging. So I did follow the usual wiki and then did, apt install vlan and then when trying to load / activate the 802.1q, via modprobe 802.1q, I get the following error.

modprobe: FATAL: Module 802.1q not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic

And I looked into this directory and there is no net folder with this 802.1q module as some searches suggested. I then upgraded the kernel to 5.4 and then even to 5.7 and the issue remains.

And it seems like code could be buggy as per this old post:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas/+bug/1712096

But I find blog posts on vlan tagging using 18.04 LTS.

Can someone help resolve this issue please? Thanks so much.